# International Transit with less than 6 months on passport

Tags: transit

My wife is Thai and we want to travel there from the USA with less than six months left on her passport, she wants to renew it while we are there.
Are there restrictions she will face while we are in transit? We will not be leaving the gate areas and only stopping over for a few hours.
Thanks.

Comment: In transit where? Each country has it own regulations, so the exact amount of time the passport is valid is important.

Comment: Well , we haven't bought the tickets yet but it looks like we will go through South Korea as our stopover.

Comment: And what are the transit requirements for passport validity of South Korea?

Comment: There is no generic answer. Put a potential flight into the IATA requirements checker. That should give the answer for your specific details: https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm

Comment: That link to IATA says she will be fine. Very helpful, thanks to all.

Comment: I went to the IATA site and put in the info and it said she could fly with no problems. But then I got curious and re-entered with false data and it said there would be no problem even if flying with an out of date passport. So I am not sure it is functioning correctly, next step I will contact the airline.